# Single apostrophe symbol making error in javascript string comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing value to button on click like below

```
echo '<b><button class="my secondary button"  onclick="onAnswerClickNew(this,\''.$myanswer.'\',4,\''.$triRow['A4'].'\')">'.'D: '.$triRow['A4'].'</button></b>';
```

and my JavaScript function code like this:

```
function onAnswerClickNew(_this, answer, option, type) {
    if (type == answer) {
        document.getElementById('correct_audio').play();
        _this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        message.appendChild(document.createTextNode("CORRECT ANSWER"));
        messageContainer.appendChild(message);
        messageContainer.classList.add("correctMessage");
    }
}
```

It's working fine if word is normal like `thats` but its not working if word is like `that's`

I have marked that if word is like `thats`, its not passing any value to function.

I am new in javascript and not able to solve the issue. Anyone can please help me for solve the matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this php? The first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using php.

If you want to make it clean, do it like this:

```
<button id="my-secondary-button"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($triRow['A4']) ?></button>
...
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('#my-secondary-button').click(function() {
        let answer = <?php echo json_encode($myanswer) ?>
        ... // call other funtion or whatever
    })
</script>
```

Summary: use **htmlspecialchars** and **json_encode**.